# How to let a user signin via third party on mobile but store token at backend

Tags: ios, oauth, access-token

Users will only be able to use a mobile app by signing into a third party service like Facebook or Twitter. Is it then possible to store the token on the backend because we're going to be manipulating some data in the backend? What would be a secure way to transfer the token?

Or even better, is there a way a user uses the mobile app to sign in but the token is sent to the server so I wouldn't have to transfer token from mobile to server?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but I remember seeing an almost exactly identical question yesterday (or 2 days ago), though I can't find it now. Was it by any chance yours question that got closed?

Comment: yeah good memory, I reworded my question because I didn't think it made sense, is this a violation on SO?

Comment: No, I don't think so - you could have edited your first question though. Or was it closed by user votes? If so, simply rewording it may not save it from the same fate ;)

Comment: haha it wasn't closed by user votes, would have made more sense to edit the question instead of deleting it

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a (hosted) microservice that does CRUD operations on (jwt) tokens. This way you just care about making REST calls to create/retrieve/decode tokens.